# Making a toy package on R, unable to use the other functions in the R file

Tags: r, function, csv, text, r-package

I am **trying to create my own R-package as an exercise**. I have followed the online tutorials by [Hillary Parker](https://hilaryparker.com/2014/04/29/writing-an-r-package-from-scratch/) and have managed to get something going.

The package I am trying to make takes a csv file, and prints the head() and tail() of the dataset. And then I wrote another function that would print the head() and tail() value in a text file.

```
ExercisePkg <- function(.csv) {

  csv <- read.csv(.csv)

  headValue <- head(csv)
  print("The head of the dataset is:")
  print(headValue)

  tailValue <- tail(csv)
  print("The tail of the dataset is:")
  print(tailValue)

  return(list(headValue, tailValue))
}
```

My next function is to print the `headValue` and the `tailValue` into a text file. For that I use `sink()` and modify the `ExercisePkg` as follows:

```
ExercisePkgTxt <- function(.csv) {

  sink('Report.txt')
  csv <- read.csv(.csv)

  headValue <- head(csv)
  print("The head of the dataset is:")
  print(headValue)

  tailValue <- tail(csv)
  print("The tail of the dataset is:")
  print(tailValue)

  return(list(headValue, tailValue))
  sink('Report.txt', append=TRUE)
}
```

I have both this functions in the code.R file as:

```
#' Function to see head and tail of a csv file
#'
#' Function is cool.
#' @param Do you love data? Defaults to TRUE
#' @keywords csv, data, head, tail,text.
#' @export ExercisePkg(),ExercisePkgTxt()
#' @examples no examples
#' ExercisePkg()
#' ExercisePKgTxt()

ExercisePkg <- function(.csv) {

      csv <- read.csv(.csv)

      headValue <- head(csv)
      print("The head of the dataset is:")
      print(headValue)

      tailValue <- tail(csv)
      print("The tail of the dataset is:")
      print(tailValue)

      return(list(headValue, tailValue))
    }

    ExercisePkgTxt <- function(.csv) {

      sink('Report.txt')
      csv <- read.csv(.csv)

      headValue <- head(csv)
      print("The head of the dataset is:")
      print(headValue)

      tailValue <- tail(csv)
      print("The tail of the dataset is:")
      print(tailValue)

      return(list(headValue, tailValue))
      sink('Report.txt', append=TRUE)
    }
```

It is kept inside the `/path/ToyPackage/R/code.R`.

After I installed the package. I tried testing it.

The `ExercisePkg("/path/dataset.csv")` worked like a charm.

But the `ExercisePkgTxt("/path/dataset.csv")` gave an error like `Error: could not find function "ExercisePkgTxt"`

I tried putting both the functions in separate R file (code.R for `ExercisePkg()` and code1.R for `ExercisePkgTxt()`) and rebuild the package. But the problem did not go away.

When I try running `document()`
I get the following:

```
>document()
Updating ToyPackage documentation
Loading ToyPackage
Writing NAMESPACE
Writing ExercisePkg.Rd
>
```

The NAMESPACE file looks like this:

```
# Generated by roxygen2: do not edit by hand

export("ExercisePkg(),ExercisePkgTxt()")
```

And when I try to install the package by install("ToyPackage"). I get the following error:

```
* installing *source* package 'ToyPackage' ...
** R
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
*** arch - i386
Error in namespaceExport(ns, exports) : 
  undefined exports: ExercisePkg(),ExercisePkgTxt()
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
*** arch - x64
Error in namespaceExport(ns, exports) : 
  undefined exports:  ExercisePkg(),ExercisePkgTxt()
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed for 'i386', 'x64'
* removing 'C:/Users/user/Documents/R/win-library/3.3/ToyPackage'
Error: Command failed (1)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Please do not give me a whole new code altogether, just suggest some changes, if any.

Thanks.

Comment: How does your NAMESPACE file look like? Did you load the package after building it? You are aware that code in a function after a call to `return` is never executed?

Comment: Creating pkgs is not a trivial task and you're first attempt is very commendable! Definitely poke at what Roland suggested  and I'd definitely read (or at least skim through) [R Packages](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz) by Hadley before proceeding much further. I think you'll find it _much_ easier to use the `roxygen` and `devtools` to streamline pkg development.

Comment: @hrbrmstr Thanks for the suggestion. I ordered the book. :)

Comment: @Roland I added the namespace in the question. It looks like it only takes the first function into account. How do I go about this?

Comment: @Roland, I added more information to the question. Please have a look.

Comment: @hrbrmstr, I added more information to the question. Please have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using Roxygen and devtools, you need to do the following:

- Include a `#' @export` directive for every function you want to export from your package
- Run `document()` before building/installing the package, to ensure the NAMESPACE file is updated.

Comment: Even after I ran `document()`, the NAMESPACE remained the same as I have provided in the question.

Comment: You also need to include `#' @export` directives for all the functions you want to export.

Comment: Like `#' @export ExercisePkg(), ExercisePkgTxt() ?` or `#' @export ExercisePkg(.csv), ExercisePkgTxt(.csv) ?`

Comment: I made some changes in the code as suggested by you. Please have a look at the modifications of the question.

Comment: I did some playing around and it worked. Please make your comment a part of the answer and I will mark it as accepted. :)